# how to split array into table

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs, html-table

I have this arrays from my JSON file

```
"Works": [
{"TypeOfWork": "scaffolding", "Status": "done"},
{"TypeOfWork": "painting", "Status": "on-going"}
]
```

I want to show a table like this

| Works | Status |
| --- | --- |
| type of work 1 | Status 1 |
| type of work 2 | Status 2 |

I have tried

```
<table ng-repeat = 'projectDetails.Works'>
<th> Works </th>
<th> Status </th>
<td> {{Works.TypeOfWorks}}</td>
<td> {{Works.Status}}</td>
</table>
```

I have also tried this one but in the form of {{projectDetails.Works(TypeOfWork)}} and also {{projectDetails.Works[TypeOfWorks]}}

```
<table>
    <th> Works </th>
    <th> Status </th>
    <td> {{projectDetails.Works.TypeOfWorks}}</td>
    <td> {{projectDetails.Works.Status}}</td>
    </table>
```

I'm getting my data from a GET function

```
$scope.projectList = [];
for (var id = 0; id < 20; id++) {
  var targetURL = 'https://happybuildings.sim.vuw.ac.nz/api/sooleandr/project.'+id+'.json';
  $http.get(targetURL).then(
    function successCall(response){
      $scope.projectList.push(response.data);
    }
  );
}

$scope.showData = function(x){
 $scope.projectDetails = x;
 };
```

In my HTML I have created buttons from the projectList and did an ng-repeat 'x in projectList'. When these buttons a clicked then it calls the showData() function, which shows the relevant data.

Comment: I doubt that an HTML5 table can be designed without the tr tag

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Works</th>
      <th>Status</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat = 'work in projectDetails.Works track by work.TypeOfWorks'>
      <td>{{work.TypeOfWorks}}</td>
      <td>{{work.Status}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You need to place your `ng-repeat` on the `tr` within `tbody`, i.e. loop through the dataset and create a table row for each.